# Project build error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, c++-cli, compiler-errors

I am getting the following error when building my project and have no idea what it means.

Environment: C++/CLI - VS2005

**EDIT:** Error message is "Project : error PRJ0003 : Error spawning 'resgen.exe'."
The weird thing is that it compiles other projects with the same configuration without any problems! I searched over the internet and it looks like it is caused by having VS2010 and VS2005 sitting together on the same machine. It is also said that reinstalling VS2005 fixes the problem.

Has any of you encountered this problem before? If yes, how did you fix it?

Comment: uhmm -- what exactly is the error message?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Forgot to include the error message. Please see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same problem and fixed it: resgen.exe resides in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin
```

however that directory was not in VS' path, only the v7.1 SDK dir was there and that version does not seem to have resgen.

Fixed simply by adding the above directory under `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories->Executable Files', after the 7.1 dir to make sure things do not get messed up. My config looks like this now:

```
....
$(WindowsSdkDir)\bin
....
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed all my problems :) Too bad I cannot do a +10!