# Error spawning 'resgen.exe' VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I just installed `Windows SDK (7.0A)` and now each time i try to either create a C++/CLI project or compile any existing C++ project i get:

```
Error spawning 'resgen.exe'.
```

I have added  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin` to "Additional Include Directories"

before i installed the Windows SDK Visual Studio 2008 was working fine... any suggestions?
I'm running Windows 7 x64 with my project built for Win32

Comment: Is this possibly the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259229/project-build-error-in-visual-studio

Comment: No, i tried that... VS 2010 compiles fine... but of course it's crap for C++ seeing how theres no intellisense...

Comment: looks like something is wrecked in VS 2008...can't even uninstall it... error: "A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling Setup"

Comment: Yikes, I've run into that before myself.  On the resgen issue, though, I found another possibility that you might try -- if you haven't already: http://ko2cv.blogspot.com/2010/08/project-error-prj0003-error-spawning.html

Comment: i tried that too... im going to reinstall vs 2008 ...found an uninstaller:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114332/visual-studio-setup-problem-a-problem-has-been-encountered-while-loading-the

Comment: Don't modify "Additional Include Directories", modify "Executable Files"

Comment: Thank you Hans. I'm in great need for this to work... so from my research i'm re-installing vs 2008 before i configure anything. i just started the re-installation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish i had waited to see if Hans suggestion would work, but here is what i did:

Original issue:
After installing MS Windows SDK 7.0A VS 2008 gave a compile error: Error spawning 'resgen.exe'

I looked everywhere online for help, nothing worked, so i tried uninstalling VS 2008

I had issues with components that prevented the uninstallation, so i used the MS fixit tool posted here:

[Visual Studio setup problem - 'A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114332/visual-studio-setup-problem-a-problem-has-been-encountered-while-loading-the)

I then reinstalled VS 2008 and now have no issues with the above error... i wish i had more time to debug to provide answers....